# simpler way to convert a function to a lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Here, Handler is a function type.
And doSomething is one of such a handler function.
addHandler register it and give it a name.
Question is are there simpler way to convert a function doSomething to a lambda?

```
typealias Handler = (cmd: String, obj: Any?) -> Any?

fun doSomething(cmd: String, obj: Any?): Any? {...}

fun addHandler(name: String, handler: Handler) {...}

fun foo() {
    addHandler("doSomething", { cmd, obj -> doSomething(cmd, obj) })
    // or in other syntax
    addHandler("doSomething") { cmd, obj -> doSomething(cmd, obj) }
}
```

Here, the phrase

```
{ cmd, obj -> doSomething(cmd, obj) }
```

is just converting a function to a lambda which has the same parameter sequence.
C++ has very simple syntax &doSomething for it. How about in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin also supports [method references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type), in your case, you can do this:

```
addHandler("doSomething", ::doSomething)
```

Comment: surprised. very nice!